# How to remove or disable hyperlink events from pdf file?

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I can display a PDF file from `byte[]` in asp.net.

The problem is that it contains hyperlinks and I want to disable or remove these hyperlink events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can libraries like [this one](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) to open and modify the PDF file and convert every hyperlink object to simple text.

Answer (score 2):

[Docotic.Pdf](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/), the library I am involved with, can be used to find hyperlinks in PDFs and remove them.

Here is the sample code that does exactly this:

```
public static void RemoveHyperlinks(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    using (PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(inputFile))
    {
        foreach (PdfPage page in doc.Pages)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < page.Widgets.Count; i++)
            {
                PdfWidget widget = page.Widgets[i];
                PdfActionArea actionArea = widget as PdfActionArea;
                if (actionArea != null)
                {
                    PdfUriAction linkAction = actionArea.Action as PdfUriAction;
                    if (linkAction != null)
                    {
                        page.Widgets.RemoveAt(i);
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        doc.Save(outputFile);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(outputFile);
    }
}
```

Please note that some viewers can detect hyperlinks from text and still present them as clickable areas even though there is not links defined in PDF itself. For example, Adobe Reader with certain settings can do just that.

P.S. I know this question is old, but maybe my answer will benefit new visitors.